# openVAS distributed architecture setup issues

Tags: ubuntu, security, vulnerabilities, ubuntu-16.04

Really hoping you can help as a college and I have spent over 2 days trying to work this out!
We have a Ubuntu server with openVAS install using the guide on the ppa site.
That works great.
But I'd like to get this working across a distributed WAN architecture, so I have one master server holding the reports and multiple scanners across the WAN in multiple locations doing the scanning, heavily reducing my bandwidth.

One the gsd GUI its asking for certs to bind to the server.
I've tried every combination of certs made by openvas-mkcert and openvas-mkcert-client and it still doesn't work.

Has anyone ever done this? the openVAS site says it's possible but with no instruction on how it should be done.

Suggestions or points in the right direction welcome!

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've sorted this out yet, but the certificates required are the CA/cacert.pem, CA/clientcert.pem and private/CA/clientkey.pem.